# Composer & Symfony Error: Boom! you are living on the edge

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

We had this **composer.json** file, which was properly working when we did **composer install**.

```
{
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4.dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.4.x-dev",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "instaclick/base-test-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "@dev",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "@dev",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Suddenly, **composer install** started failing with the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle 2.4.x-dev exists as symfony/assetic-bundle[2.0.x-dev, 2.1.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, dev-master, 2.7.x-dev, dev-node-visitor, v2.1.0, v2.1.0-RC2, v2.1.1, v2.1.1-beta1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.3.0, v2.3.0-beta1, v2.3.1, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-beta1, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.8.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
```

So I tried updating the **composer.json** with exact version numbers from the previously working **composer.lock** file like this:

```
{
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.3.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.x",
    "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.x",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.x",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.x",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.x",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.x",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.x",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.1.1",
    "instaclick/base-test-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.x",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.x",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "@dev",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "@dev",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
     "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, at least I am able to install packages, but at the end of the installation, I get this error:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Boom! you are living on the edge ;) The AdminBundle requires the CoreBundle!
  Please add ``"sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev"`` into your composer.json file and add the SonataCoreBundle into the AppKernel');
```

This **composer.json** configuration (before failing) was able to work properly without adding SonataCoreBundle to AppKernel.

The Symfony version is 2.3.

I'd appreciate any suggestions and help. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you add ``"sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev"`` into your composer.json file and add the SonataCoreBundle into the AppKernel? :)

Comment: Sounds like you have in fact actually upgraded sonata admin. I've seen this when I updated it.

Comment: @1ed: I have added those, and it installed without any errors, but now it throws this error when I run **console cache:clear** command:

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\Mapper\DoctrineORMMapper::loadClassMetadata() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs given, called in ..... ContainerAwareEventManager.php on line 63 and defined in ..... /vendor/sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle/Mapper/DoctrineORMMapper.php on line 157